# How to temporarily add an outline to :hover elements

Tags: javascript, css

I'm creating a bookmarklet that displays some information on the first element you click on after running the bookmarklet. I would love to have it so the element you are hovering over has an outline, but only before you click. After you have selected an element, the outline would no longer appear when hovering (except if it already did so before my bookmarklet).

To get the clicked element, this works fine for me:

```
function getClickedElement(e) {
    document.removeEventListener("click", getClickedElement);
    e.preventDefault();
    clickedElement = e.target || e.srcElement;
    // Some code that displays information on clickedElement...
}
document.addEventListener("click", getClickedElement);
```

But I don't know how to do the CSS. It would work like all elements gain this CSS:

```
:hover {
    outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

while selecting an element, but that stops once an element has been selected. Hope that all made sense.

Comment: @JoshuaK my friendly suggestion: post an answer when you think you know it. Comments are for clarification. Enjoy your rep. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small example with the principle explained!

1. If the user clicks on the element, add a specific class.
2. CSS Rule adds outline-border only if the element does not match the selector inside the [:not pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)!

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  var target = evt.target || evt.source;
  if(!target.classList.contains('element')) return;
  if(target.classList.contains('selected'))
    target.classList.remove('selected');
  else
    target.classList.add('selected');
}, true);
```

```css
div.element {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:silver;
  display:inline-block;
}
.element.selected {
  background-color:black;
}
.element:not(.selected):hover {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, this is perfect. I wish I could accept you both, but this definitely deserves it.